# Yahoo Boss return more than 50 results

Tags: rest-client, yahoo-boss-api

I am sending queries to my RESTclient for example

```
url = "http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web?q="Yorkshire%20Capital"ANDfraud&format=xml&abstract=long"
```

and I am noticing that there is a maximum of 50 results being returned each time. How can I change the query in order to get all the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, by design.

http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/#pricing

```
Query Type  Definition                  Price/1000 Queries (USD)    Max. Results/Query
Full Web    Web Search results only.    $0.80                       50
```

Comment: Except that now Full Web raised to $1.50

Comment: Thanks for the update davide I haven't used Yahoo Boss in a while